# Custom Post within a custom post

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a custom post called "A".

I have created another custom post called "B".

I want the hierarchy of B to be a sibling of A, that is

http://www.mysite.com/A/B/name-of-post

I have A as a custom post type because I want to change the layout, and make it loop through all the items of A and B has another style of it's own.

Everything works, when I see the archive of A I see the posts for type A, and same as B (see the posts of B) but when I click on the archive of B to see each individual post, I get NOT FOUND (and yes I have gone to permalink settings).

These are my rules:

For post type A:

```
$args = array(
    // ... other args removed for clarity
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'A' )
    // ...
);
```

For POST TYPE B:

```
$args = array(
    // ... other args removed for clarity
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'A/B' )
    // ...
);
```

Appreciate any help on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Okay the answer is simple (was able to fix this myself).

What you need to do is put another directory (let's call it C) where the rewriting rules will be made.

So for post type B, it would be:

```
$args = array(
    // ... other args removed for clarity
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'A/C/B' )
    // ...
);
```

It's a bit cumbersome but it works nevertheless.